# Jquery checked selector within variable

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling with this, not even found if it's possible..

Having a variable like this

```
var this.$others = $("input:checkbox[name *='" + container + "']");
```

that stores a list of checkboxes, I want to check in another function the number of those that are checked. I can do that:

```
 var numberOfNotChecked = self.$others.not(':checked').length;
```

and it works fine, but I thought it would be more clear for the rest of the code which is going to use this variable to have the opposite one (i.e. the number of checkboxes checked)

So I'm trying this

```
var numberOfChecked = self.$others.find(':checked').length;
```

And it doesn't come as they are always 0. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: find checked checkboxes in checkboxes is not going to return you anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `filter`, not `find`:

```
var numberOfChecked = self.$others.filter(':checked').length;
```

You are using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) which looks for elements within an element. For example:

```
<div id="bar"><p>some text</p></div>
<script>
    var foo = $('#bar').find('p'); // foo.length = 1
</script>
```

On the other hand, [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) returns a jQuery collection of elements which match the given selector from an existing collection. (Exactly what you're trying to do).

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var numberOfChecked = self.$others.find(':checked').length;
```

To:

```
var numberOfChecked = self.$others.filter(':checked').length;
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhavalbharadva/L25NB/76/)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of find use filter function :

```
var numberOfChecked = self.$others.filter(':checked').length;
```